# TestNG MacOS Eclipse: /bin/sh: /platform-tools/adb: No such file or directory java.lang.Exception: Adb Connect Command Failed to Exe

Tags: eclipse, macos, path, adb, android-sdk-tools

I'm currently using TestNG xml in Eclipse on a MacOS system for a simple test script, I'm not sure why I'm getting the error:
Adb Connect Command Failed /bin/sh: /platform-tools/adb: No such file or directory.

Currently all adb commands work in my terminal when I enter them, such as just adb, or adb connect. I checked within the platform-tools and there is the adb executable. So this test script is running adb connect, but it's not even recognizing adb within the Eclipse terminal. **I was thinking it could be an Eclipse issue?**

I read through other posts, and they all have simple environment variable problems or failed downloads, but nothing about it working perfectly fine in terminal but not in eclipse testng script.

I thought it may have been a problem in my environment variables, which I'm using zshrc, but I have all the variables set, which is why it works in terminal.

`export ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=/Users/andrewzhang/Library/android/sdk`
`export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/`
`export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools/adb`
`export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools`
`export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin`
`export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/emulator`

So it's not a file issue or an environment variable, is there some kind of reset or source ~/.zshrc that I can do in Eclipse?

Comment: Have you checked all of the preference pages? Anything about how TestNG launches tests?

Comment: I have checked the preferences like the Run Configurations, but nothing specific. The main thing is that someone was saying there should be an Android settings tab, but I don't see that on my MacOS Eclipse.